# get next next post in single.php

Tags: posts, next-post-link

I really need your help.

in my single.php I had to get the next post in the same category

(which i already have by:

$in_same_cat = true;

$excluded_categories = '';

$previous = false;

$next_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous);)

now I need the **next next** post and also in the opposite direction  **previous previous** post

thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

surprisingly,I found the answer myself...

I am using the same function as I used for next/previous post

(get_adjacent_post() ) 
but sending the the next/previous post which I already found as a parameter

```
$in_same_cat = true;

$excluded_categories = '';

$previous = true;

$previous_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous);

$previous_previous_post = 
get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous,$previous_post);

$previous = false;

$next_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous);

$next_next_post = get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat,$excluded_categories,$previous,$next_post);
```

but...we haven't finished yet..
we need to add this code to the function declaration in wp-includes/link-template.php

```
function get_adjacent_post($in_same_cat = false, $excluded_categories = '', $previous = true,$mypost = null) {
    global  $wpdb;

//if specific post wasnt sent to function it takes the global one and checks if its empty before using it.

    if ( empty( $mypost ) )
    {
        global $post;
        if(empty( $post ))
            return null;
        $mypost=$post;
    }
//...
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi
Try to use the get_adjacent_post function according to this link
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-next-post-id
you can create a small loop that will get the ID of the next post and then use
the function again on the ID that you've received to get the next next ID.

```
$prevPost = get_previous_post();
$i = 0;  
$num_prev_posts = 4;  
while ($i < $num_prev_posts) //needs to check if $prevPost exists. while ($i < $num_prev_posts && !empty($prevPost)) doesn't work. 
{  
    get_permalink($post->ID); //and other such functions that work on the global $post should now work.  
    $i++;  
    $prevPost = get_previous_post(); // and then there should be a check if $prevPost is empty or not  
    print_r($prevPost);  
}
```

this will bring the previous 4 posts.
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/get-next-5-posts-from-the-current-post

Answer (score 2):

See answer here for some code that fetches several adjacent posts:

[Getting the Next and Previous Posts Titles in the Sidebar?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2759/getting-the-next-and-previous-posts-titles-in-the-sidebar/2761#2761)